# Detect USB bus failure on Win CE device from a separate PC

Tags: performance, windows

I am testing a device running Win CE that is having issues with the USB bus failing intermittently. Manually, it takes me hours to reproduce the bug so I'm trying to automate this process. So how do I detect USB failure on this device from another PC?

A little background:  There is power at the USB port, just no data activity between D+ and D-.  Also, I will be reproducing this bug by controlling relays that are attached to hard button inputs to the device to simulate user interaction.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It could be anything from a host or device device driver problem, firmware problem (digital part), analog problem and I even saw bad cables causing intermittent problems.

If you have access to the WinCE USB drivers (e.g. through logs, or debug prints added to the code) than it's a good place to start isolating the problem.

what is your budget ? there USB bus sniffers/analyzers in different levels and price ranges. Using them will require some learning and time invested, so even the cheaper ones are not free, but they might help you visualize what is going on on the bus, some can record and playback the session or run simulations.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The WinCE device was developed by another group in another country, so I'm flying blind mostly.  I have verified with a scope that comms are failing as far up as between the USB hub chip and the CPU. The device soft resets itself frequently (I believe in a hacky attempt to fix another bug) and the failure eventually occurs after one of these resets.

Comment: unfortunately this is too broad to answer remotely.  but the driver is the best place to start at, so try communicating with the other team

Comment: I forgot to mention I have found a way to interface with an oscilloscope through the command line which I believe I can query to see if bus activity is occurring after each reset.